# Python algorythm for finding distance

Tags: python, matrix

So I have training task for finding distance for Lockscreen
As input we have random sequence for 1 to 9, each number in sequence can only be followed by his neighbors(like on phone's lock screen).
I.E.

```
matrix=[[6, 1, 9], [5, 2, 8], [4, 3, 7]]
hits = [ 9,8,1,2,3,4]
and length of this seq. will be 1+1.44+1+1+1
so need to write a function for any random seq.
matrix = [[0] * 3 for i in range(3)]
matrix[0][0]=6
matrix[0][1]=1
matrix[0][2]=9
matrix[1][0]=5
matrix[1][1]=2
matrix[1][2]=8
matrix[2][0]=4
matrix[2][1]=3
matrix[2][2]=7

summ=[]

for i in range(len(matrix)):
    if hits[0] in matrix[i]:
        if matrix[i+1][hits[0]+1]==hits[1] or \
                matrix[i+1][hits[0]-1]==hits[1] or \
                matrix[i-1][hits[0]+1]==hits[1] or \
                matrix[i-1][hits[0]-1]==hits[1]:
            sum+=1.44
```

Comment: You haven't told us yet what's the problem you are facing. Do you get an error? Not the expected output? You think it could be done better?

Comment: Yes, it is complicated, I just brute force trying to check all possible outcomes for the next number in list...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
matrix = [[6, 1, 9], [5, 2, 8], [4, 3, 7]]
hits = [9, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4]


def distance(a: int, b: int) -> float:
    """
    Calculate the distance between two points a,b
    a, b are numbers taken from the list 'hits'
    """
    # find the index of a in matrix
    # enumerate(matrix) returns a list of tuples (row_index, row) 
    # enumerate(matrix) returns
    # [(0, [6, 1, 9]),
    #  (1, [5, 2, 8]),
    #  (2, [4, 3, 7])]
    #
    # but by writting "enumerate(matrix) if a in row" we get only the data where the row contains "a"
    # for example, if a is 6, then "enumerate(matrix) if a in row" will return (0, [6, 1, 9])
    # which is stored in row_index=0 and row=[6, 1, 9]
    # (row_idx, row.index(a)) extracts the index of a in row and returns (0, 0)
    # index_a = (0, 0) because (0,0)=(row_idx=0, [6, 1, 9].index(a=6)=0)


    index_a = [(row_idx, row.index(a))
               for row_idx, row in enumerate(matrix) if a in row][0]

    index_b = [(row_idx, row.index(b))
                for row_idx, row in enumerate(matrix) if b in row][0]

    # calculate the distance between index_a and index_b
    # aplying pytagoras theorem
    # distance = sqrt((index_a.X - index_b.X)^2 + (index_a.Y - index_b.Y)^2)
    return ((index_a[0]-index_b[0])**2 + (index_a[1]-index_b[1])**2)**0.5


totalDistance = sum(distance(a, b) for a, b in zip(hits[:-1], hits[1:]))
# the former code makes pairs of values from "hits" and then calculates the distance between them
# the pair of values are obtained from zip(hits[:-1], hits[1:])
# hits[:-1] is the first part of the list,  EXCLUDING THE LAST value
# hits[1:] is the second part of the list, EXCLUDING THE FIRST value
# hits[:-1] = [9, 8, 1, 2, 3]
# hits[1:] =  [8, 1, 2, 3, 4]
#
# The zip function creates a list of pairs of values from the two lists
# zip([9, 8, 1, 2, 3], [8, 1, 2, 3, 4]) = [(9, 8), (8, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
#
# [(9, 8), (8, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)] is stored in a,b, and used to calculate the distance between them
# by calling the function distance(a, b)
#
# (distance(a, b) for a, b in zip(hits[:-1], hits[1:])) = [1.0, 1.41, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
#
# totalDistance = sum([1.0, 1.41, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]) = 5.0

print(f"{totalDistance=:.2f}")
```

Comment: You are Python hero!
meh, if only I could understand how you came to this)

Comment: I added comments explaining the code. You need to understand python "list comprehension" to understand it.